# Log4j vulnerability while using Scala and Spark with sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, log4j

I am working on a scala spark project.
I am using below dependencies:

```
 libraryDependencies ++=
    Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" ,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"  ,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.0"
    ),
```

with scalaVersion set to :

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

and i am getting below error:

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api;2.11.1: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api;2.11.1 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}::
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api;2.11.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1/ivys/ivy.xml: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 403
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api;2.11.1: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1/ivys/ivy.xml: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 403
```

Security team has reached out to us to delete the vulnerable log4j-core jar. After which the projects which are using it as transitive dependencies are failing.

Is there a way on just upgrading the log4j version without upgrading scala or spark versions?
It should be a way where i can force the compiler to not fetch log4j-core jar of previous version which is vulnerable and in its place can use 2.17.2 version which is not vulnerable.

I have tried :

```
  dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.17.2"
```

also i have excludeAll option in sbt with spark dependencies but both solutions didnt worked out for me.

Comment: Spark doesn't use log4j 2.x but log4j 1.2, and trying to embed/ship job with log4j2 would be useless.

Comment: What should be the way to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made few updates:

Added below settings to my sbt project:
[image]

Updated below settings to use a newer version: in build.properties and assembly.sbt respectively

```
sbt.version=1.6.2
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "1.1.0")
```

Added the log4j dependencies on the top so that any transitive dependency now can use a newer version.

Given below is the sample snippet of one of my project:

```
name := "project name"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.**" -> "shaded.@1").inAll
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(
  test in assembly := {}
)

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.17.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.17.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.17.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.0"
```

Below should be provided only in case of conflicts between dependencies if there are any:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "slf4j", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first  
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```